# Fullscreen slideshow using Python 2

Tags: python, tkinter, slideshow, fullscreen

Currently, my code can cycle through a list of images and can display each image fora certain amount of time. However, it only opens a small window to display the image, which doesn't even fill the entire window. I want to display each image full screen, is there any way in which I could do this?

Also, the script only works for GIFs, is there any way in which I could alter it to accept other types of files such as JPEG.

My code is:

```
from itertools import cycle
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, image_files, delay):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        w, h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
        self.delay = delay
        self.pictures = cycle((tk.PhotoImage(file=image), image)
                          for image in image_files)            
        self.picture_display = tk.Label(self)
        self.picture_display.pack()

    def show_slides(self):
        img_object, img_name = next(self.pictures)
        self.picture_display.config(image=img_object)
        self.title(img_name)
        self.after(self.delay, self.show_slides)
    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()

 delay = 3500
 image_files = ["/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object1.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object12ndImage.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object13rdImage.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object14thImage.gif"]

 app = App(image_files, delay)
 app.show_slides()
 app.run()
```

Comment: Yes to both of your questions. You can resize images to fit or fill the frame they are in and you can also use the `PIL`(Pillow) library to work with other image formats such as jpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My example is using Python 3.x however you should have no problem changing your imports to work with Python 2.x.

That said I would personally use a tracking variable to keep track of the index of our photo list. With this we can run everything we need to run from inside the `show_slides` method. The main issue you need to address is the resizing of your images. This can be done with `PIL`. We can open the image based on the current path then resize it. We then load the resized image to the label. We can also use `os.path.basename()` to get the file name to use on our titles. That said currently the way your program is set up no title will be displaced in full screen.

Take a look at the below code and let me know if you have any questions.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
import os


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, image_files, delay):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.w = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.h = self.winfo_screenheight()
        self.overrideredirect(1)
        self.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.w, self.h))
        self.delay = delay
        self.pictures = []
        self.track_img_ndex = 0
        for img in image_files:
            self.pictures.append(img)            
        self.picture_display = tk.Label(self)
        self.picture_display.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    def show_slides(self):
        if self.track_img_ndex < len(self.pictures):
            x = self.pictures[self.track_img_ndex]
            self.track_img_ndex +=1
            original_image = Image.open(x)
            resized = original_image.resize((self.w, self.h),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            new_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
            self.picture_display.config(image=new_img)
            self.picture_display.image = new_img
            self.title(os.path.basename(x))
            self.after(self.delay, self.show_slides)
        else:
            print("End of list!")

delay = 3500
image_files = ["/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object1.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object12ndImage.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object13rdImage.gif",
     "/media/pi/RASPBERRY/object14thImage.gif"]

app = App(image_files, delay)
app.show_slides()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

And if I will like put up buttons to move on?

```
Tkinter.Button(frame, text='Previous picture', command=lambda: move(-1)).pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)
Tkinter.Button(frame, text='Next picture', command=lambda: move(+1)).pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)
Tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=root.quit).pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT)
```